# Updating product price overrides every single property of default store view

Tags: magento-1.8, php, api

I have a schema with multiple websites, one store for each website, and multiple storeviews for each store / website.

I want to update a price in the Default Values with the following code:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
$product->setPrice($price)->save();
```

The price is updated, but the model API overrides every single property of the product for the default store view of the store of the default website (with *overrides* I mean that the **Use Default Value** tick box is untoggled after the update).

How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it like this.

```
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')
    ->updateAttributes(array($productId), array('price'=>$price), 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to load the product from the Default Store View:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId(0)->load($productId);
$product->setPrice($price)->save();
```